# time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, summation

Hi all i'm trying to predict/calculate the time complexity of an algorithm but i'm having some difficulties with the summations

the algorithm:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < i * i; j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
            //operation
```

So far I have to following:
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i^2-1} \sum_{k=0}^{i-1} 1  
$$
$$
= \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i^2-1} i
$$

But now I'm stuck with the upper bound. I thought something like this
$$
= \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2}
$$

But if i take a look at the algorithm it will be at most $O(n^4) $ ...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Following your derivation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i^2-1}i
=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} i^3
=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} O(N^3) 
=O(N^4)$$

Notice that $\sum_{j=0}^{i^2 -1}i$ equals $i^2 \cdot i$ since the index is $j$.